# rdlc with subreport and object classes

Tags: class, object, report, rdlc

I'm using Microsoft Reports (rdlc), and I need to create report with subreport. As a data source I created two Object Classes, PositionObject and PositionSubElementObject. PositionObject is data source for the main report, and PositionSubElementObject is a data source for the subreport. 
When I run this two reports separately, everything is ok, but when I create report with subreport, I'm gettin error in subreport.

Both object classes have the same field, IDPosition, and that field is parameter which I'm passing to subreport from the main report.

I hope that someone knows where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are setting the data source for the sub report in the event ReportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing.